# Python, Call a class function from another class

Tags: python, class, call, twisted

Can you anyone please help me (noob) call the **broadcast function** from  class **BroadcastServerFactory** in **class process**, as per attached code

I have tried so many methods of call a function from another class, but no solution

```
import time, sys
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import threading
import socket
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File

from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory, \
                               WebSocketServerProtocol, \
                               listenWS


class process(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, buffer3):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.buffer3 = buffer3


    def run(self):
        factory.broadcast("I don't know what I'm doing!")



class BroadcastServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

   def onOpen(self):
      self.factory.register(self)

   def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
      if not binary:
         self.factory.broadcast("'%s' from %s" % (msg, self.peerstr))

   def connectionLost(self, reason):
      WebSocketServerProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
      self.factory.unregister(self)


class BroadcastServerFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
   """
   Simple broadcast server broadcasting any message it receives to all
   currently connected clients.
   """

   def __init__(self, url, debug = False, debugCodePaths = False):
      WebSocketServerFactory.__init__(self, url, debug = debug, debugCodePaths = debugCodePaths)
      self.clients = []
      self.tickcount = 0
      self.tick()

   def tick(self):
      self.tickcount += 1
      self.broadcast("'tick %d' from server" % self.tickcount)
      reactor.callLater(1, self.tick)

   def register(self, client):
      if not client in self.clients:
         print "registered client " + client.peerstr
         self.clients.append(client)

   def unregister(self, client):
      if client in self.clients:
         print "unregistered client " + client.peerstr
         self.clients.remove(client)

   def broadcast(self, msg):
      print "broadcasting message '%s' .." % msg
      for c in self.clients:
         c.sendMessage(msg)
         print "message sent to " + c.peerstr


class BroadcastPreparedServerFactory(BroadcastServerFactory):
   """
   Functionally same as above, but optimized broadcast using
   prepareMessage and sendPreparedMessage.
   """

   def broadcast(self, msg):
      print "broadcasting prepared message '%s' .." % msg
      preparedMsg = self.prepareMessage(msg)
      for c in self.clients:
         c.sendPreparedMessage(preparedMsg)
         print "prepared message sent to " + c.peerstr


def testing():
    buffer2 - "hello"
    myDisplay = process(buffer2)
    myDisplay.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

   if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'debug':
      log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
      debug = True
   else:
      debug = False
   level_scheduler = Scheduler()
   level_scheduler.add_interval_job(testing, seconds=5)
   level_scheduler.start()
   #ServerFactory = BroadcastServerFactory
   ServerFactory = BroadcastPreparedServerFactory

   factory = ServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000",
                           debug = debug,
                           debugCodePaths = debug)

   factory.protocol = BroadcastServerProtocol
   factory.setProtocolOptions(allowHixie76 = True)
   listenWS(factory)

   webdir = File(".")
   web = Site(webdir)
   reactor.listenTCP(8080, web)


   reactor.run()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the class instance of `BroadcastServerFactory` to be called to the class instance that calls it `process` on creation

```
class process(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, buffer3m, broadcast_server_factory):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.buffer3 = buffer3

        self.factory = broadcast_server_factory

    def run(self):
        self.factory.broadcast("I don't know what I'm doing!")
```

and then call it (it's assigned as `self.factory` in the `run` statement. I can't see where you create a `process` class in your `__main__` but it will be created with something like

```
 p = process(buffer, factory)
```

Aside: Using capital letters for class names is considered good form in python `process -> Process`

Comment: Master @ you game, you are a life saviour.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that the use of threading both in the question and in this answer is probably incorrect and will only work sometimes.  `broadcast` is not thread-safe and must be called in the same thread `reactor.run` is called in.